# The correct way to handle and extend Node in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

In my quest to have better coding practices, I have come across a coding idea that I have been doing for a long time and I even see programmers from this site, who I consider experts, use the same coding idea.

For example in the code below I extend Pane. To get the class' children I have always called `this.getChildren()` in this situation. Today I noticed Netbeans gives a warning message, so I looked it up and found that to get rid of the warning I should use `super.getChildren()`. Is the recommend way I should handle this situation in the future or is `this.getChildren()` just as good?

```
public class FlashCard extends Pane
{    
    FlashCard(int num1, int num2, int answer)
    {

        Label lblNum1 = new Label(Integer.toString(num1));
        Label lblNum2 = new Label(Integer.toString(num2));
        Label lblAnswer = new Label(Integer.toString(answer));

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(lblNum1, lblNum2, lblAnswer);          
        super.getChildren().add(vbox);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume the warning is that you shouldn't invoke overridable methods from a constructor (or something similar). The best (simplest and safest) approach, if it suits your requirements, is just to make `FlashCard` final.

Comment: Yes, that is the error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Item 17 from Josh Bloch's *"Effective Java"* (Second Edition): "Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it". (I **strongly** recommend reading this book, if you haven't already.) Specifically:

> There are a few more restrictions that a class must obey to allow inheritance. **Constructors must not invoke overridable methods.**

The basic problem is that if you were to subclass `FlashCard` and override `getChildren()` in a way that depended on initialization performed in the subclass constructor, your code would break. The `FlashCard` constructor would be invoked before the subclass constructor, so it would invoke `getChildren()` *before* the initialization had taken place. In a somewhat artificial example:

```
public class SpecialFlashCard extends FlashCard {

    private ObservableList<Node> subclassChildren ;

    public SpecialFlashCard(int num1, int num2, int answer) {
        super(num1, num2, answer);
        subclassChildren = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Node> getChildren() {
        return subclassChildren ;
    }
}
```

If the `FlashCard` constructor invoked `this.getChildren()`, then invoking the subclass constructor would throw a `NullPointerException`, because the superclass constructor would attempt to add elements to `subclassChildren` before it was initialized. On the other hand, if the `FlashCard` constructor invoked `super.getChildren()`, then the subclass would not behave as expected (because `getChildren()` would return a list that did not include the labels).

The simplest approaches here are either to prohibit subclassing of `FlashCard` or to avoid subclassing `Pane` in the first place.

To prohibit subclassing, make `FlashCard` final:

```
public final class FlashCard extends Pane {

    public FlashCard(int num1, int num2, int answer) {

        Label lblNum1 = new Label(Integer.toString(num1));
        Label lblNum2 = new Label(Integer.toString(num2));
        Label lblAnswer = new Label(Integer.toString(answer));

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(lblNum1, lblNum2, lblAnswer);          
        this.getChildren().add(vbox);
    }
}
```

This completely avoids the problem, because now you cannot subclass `FlashCard`, and so you cannot override its `getChildren()` method (you are no longer calling an overridable method from the constructor).

An alternative approach (which I tend to prefer), is not to subclass `Pane` in the first place. This is Item 16 from *Effective Java*: "Favor composition over inheritance".

```
public class FlashCard {

    private final Pane pane ;

    public FlashCard(int num1, int num2, int answer) {
        Label lblNum1 = new Label(Integer.toString(num1));
        Label lblNum2 = new Label(Integer.toString(num2));
        Label lblAnswer = new Label(Integer.toString(answer));

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(lblNum1, lblNum2, lblAnswer); 

        this.pane = new Pane();         
        this.pane.getChildren().add(vbox);
    }

    public Pane asPane() {
        return pane ;
    }
}
```

(Note that the constructor does not invoke any overridable methods.)

This allows essentially the same functionality as your existing `FlashCard` class, but with a slightly modified API. E.g. instead of

```
FlashCard flashCard = new FlashCard(6, 9, 42);
someContainer.getChildren().add(flashCard);
```

you do

```
FlashCard flashCard = new FlashCard(6, 9, 42);
someContainer.getChildren().add(flashCard.asPane());
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This really clears things up for me.