# I have a class that extends a javafx stackpane and within that class would like to create a menubar containing a menu with items

Tags: java, javafx

here's the code:

```
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import csc2a.desc.model.*;

public class CrisisPane extends StackPane{
    //create menu
    Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");

    //create menu items
    MenuItem openFileItem = new MenuItem("Open file");

    //add menu item to menu
    fileMenu.getItems().add(openFileItem); //syntax error here 

    //create menu bar 
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

    //add menu to menubar
    menubar.getMenus().add(fileMenu); //and syntax error here
}
```

every time i try adding a new menu item and adding the menu to the menubar i get the error 
(Syntax error on token "getItems", Identifier expected after this token)

this is how my lecturer explained it to us and represented it in code
I'm really new to javafx and have some basic java concepts down but have experience in c++ already and i'm using eclipse as an IDE

Comment: don't show ad-hoc code, chances are that it doesn't even compile (as yours, there's a spelling error). Check your imports, make sure you import the fx versions (and _not_ the awt classes) And unrelated: don't extend layouts - instead, configure them as needed

Comment: You need to call those two methods inside the constructor.

Comment: Also may be worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877557/the-correct-way-to-handle-and-extend-node-in-javafx